# JQuery Toggle Effect and HTML List

Tags: jquery, list, toggle

I want to create an effect when I pressed button which was made with css.
That is my list structure and I want to use fadeToggle  item by item, but I couldn't.

```
<div id="nav" >

    <span class="nav_btn"></span>   

        <ul id="list">

            <a href=""><li id="1">1</li></a>
            <a href=""><li id="2">2</li></a>
            <a href=""><li id="3">3</li></a>
            <a href=""><li id="4">4</li></a>
            <a href=""><li id="5">5</li></a>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is working but it is for all list element other words, it's for ul element.

```
$("span.nav_btn").click(function() {

$("ul#list").fadeToggle("4000");
```

})

I wonder why that code is not working:

```js
$("span.nav_btn").click(function() {
$("li#1").fadeToggle("500");
$("li#2").fadeToggle("1000");
$("li#3").fadeToggle("1500");
$("li#4").fadeToggle("2000");
$("li#5").fadeToggle("2500");
})
```

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference, and without access to a computer right now, I can't test... but you should have the list items <li> as children of the <ul>, rather than the <a href's.

Comment: Thanks for answer Luke, but result was not change. It isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the quotes from the duration works as (I believe) you want this to. This is because with quotes you were passing the value as a string. By removing them you are correctly passing a number.

Use:

```
$("li#1").fadeToggle(500);
$("li#2").fadeToggle(1000);
$("li#3").fadeToggle(1500);
$("li#4").fadeToggle(2000);
$("li#5").fadeToggle(2500);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d94ur5yc/